# How can I prevent ListBox from unselecting items after right click

Tags: ms-access-2007

i have a form that there is a list box inside that. after selection of items (usually 20 items) and right click the mouse on items it should open another pop up form,the problem is after right click selected items will be unselected except one item that there is mouse on that.

how can i prevent list box from deselecting items after right click .

the code for mouse right click is like below:

```
Private Sub ItemList_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
 Const RIGHTBUTTON = 2
 Dim udtPos As POINTAPI
 Dim frm As Access.Form

If Button = RIGHTBUTTON Then

Set mp = New [*clsMousePosition]
GetCursorPos udtPos


DoCmd.OpenForm "frmshortcut"
DoCmd.MoveSize udtPos.x * mp.TwipsPerPixelX, udtPos.y * mp.TwipsPerPixelY
Forms!frmshortcut!txtparameter = Me.ItemList.Value


 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the listbox bound to a multivalue field?

Comment: yes row source of list box is query with 5 fields

Comment: But is the field in `ControlSource` a multivalue field?

Comment: no control source is not a multivalue field

Answer (score 0):

If `Multi Select` property is set to `Simple` this should not be happening.

I am assuming that `Mutli Select` is set to `Extended`, in which case you should press the `CTRL` button while right clicking the item with the mouse to keep existing selections just as you would with left clicking.

In a nutshell: The right click does the same as a left click just it also opens up a context menu.